# Migrating ADODB Connection to .NET

Tags: .net, sql, connection-string

What kind of connection strings are these?

```
DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****;
Driver={SQL Server};Server=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****;Database=*****;
```

I'm working on migrating an application from classic ASP to .NET.  In the old app, connection strings like the ones above were used with the ADODB.Connection object:

```
set AppDBcn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set AppRS = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

I've tried using .NET's `ADODB.Connection` class and the `OdbcConnection` class to open these, but keep getting connection errors like "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" or "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied."

Am I using the wrong .NET connection classes for these types of connection strings, or is there something more sinister going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reference there. Connection String for .NET

[Connection String for .NET](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
             "Data Source=myServerAddress;
              Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
              User Id=myUsername;
              Password=myPassword;");
```